# Permutation ( selection of 4 letters from 12)

Tags: permutations

Question : how many different selections of four letters from the twelve letters of the word REFRIGERATOR contain no R's and two E's?

My attempt:

If there are to be no R's then the selection is limited to

E F I G E A T O

(2 . 1.  6 . 5) = 60 
Then 60/2! = 30 selections of 4 letters

I am unsure of whether I am accurate in completely removing the Rs from the selection. Any help appreciated

Comment: If you find the answer helpful don't forget to $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we do not need letter $R$, we need to choose from EFIGEATO. Since we need the selection that consists of $2$ E's, we need to choose from FIAGATO. Note that the positions we need are

```
   EE_ _, E_E_, E_ _E, _EE_, _E_E, _ _ EE
```

That is the number of arrangements of $2$ same letter E among four positions $=\dbinom{4}{2}=6$

The two blanks are filled by the letters from FIAGATO.

The letter for the first blank can be chosen in $\dbinom{6}{1}=6$ ways

The letter for the second blank can be chosen in $\dbinom{5}{1}=5$ ways.

Therefore, the total number of selections are $6\times6\times5=180$